# How to have two ImageViews appear side by side in Titanium

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I can't get two ImageViews to appear side by side in a Titanium iOS app.

My Alloy code looks like this:

```html
<Alloy> 
 <Window class='container' statusBarStyle='Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT'>
  <View height='20' top='0' left='0' backgroundColor='#01B6AC'></View>
  <View id = 'savedContents' layout='vertical' top='20'>
  </View>
  <Require type='view' src='bottomBar' id='bottomBar'/>
  <Widget id="fa" src="com.mattmcfarland.fontawesome"/>
 </Window> 
</Alloy>
```

My Controller code looks like this:

```js
row = Ti.UI.createView({
 width:'100%',
 height:150,
 layout:'horizontal'
}); 

image1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
 image:'http://www.outnow.io/assets/img/small511by309/'+venueDetails[0]["image1"],
 width:'50%',
 height:150,
 left:0,
 top:0
}); 

image2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
 image:'http://www.outnow.io/assets/img/small511by309/'+venueDetails[1]["image1"],
 width:'50%',
 height:150,
 left:0,
 top:0
});

row.add(image1);
row.add(image2); 
$.savedContents.add(row);

$.saved.open();
```

Only image1 appears. Both images are ok and if I comment out either one of the row.add() calls the remaining image appears fine. I am trying to get the two images to appear side by side taking up 50% of the width each.

Comment: try to decrease the width of both `imageView` to `49%` or `48%`, or remove the layout form `row` and the give `left : '0dp'` to `image1` and `right : '0dp'` to `image2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine for me, try to strip any differences from your code:

```
<Alloy>
  <Window backgroundColor="white">
    <View layout="vertical" top="20">
      <View layout="horizontal" height="150">
        <View width="50%" left="0" backgroundColor="red" />
        <View width="50%" left="0" backgroundColor="green" />
      </View>
      <View layout="horizontal" height="150">
        <View width="50%" left="0" backgroundColor="blue" />
        <View width="50%" left="0" backgroundColor="yellow" />
      </View>
    </View>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fokke I will try that out.

Comment: Great! That works. I think the problem was in the way I had defined the enclosing view but following your code exactly it works. Thanks.

Comment: Great example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are inserting both pictures on the left edge (both `left` properties are set to `0`). Try to change the `left=0` for `image2` to `right=0`and delete the `left`property. Your code for ìmage2`should now look like this:

```
image2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image:'http://www.outnow.io/assets/img/small511by309/'+venueDetails[1]["image1"],
    width:'50%',
    height:150,
    right:0, //Changed this one to right
    top:0
});
```

Comment: Thanks Robin. I tried that and I am still only seeing the one image.

Comment: Does the picture you see have the right size(especially the correct width)? For debugging leave out the image property for both pictures and give them a border. Set the border width of the picture you don't see to a greater value than the  one of the other picture. So you can see whether both views lay on top of each other. To achieve the same thing you could also make the image you see transparent.

Comment: There must be something basic about the horizontal layout mode that I am not understanding. If I change the layout of the row view to composite it all works fine (having made the changes you suggested)!

Comment: Please try to remove the `layout=vertical` from the view in your Alloy XML. It is just a guess I will dig deeper tomorrow.

Comment: It is hard to come up with a solution because your code seems to be fine.. Why do you need the layout and don't use a composite one?

Comment: Actually, now that I have found that composite works ok I don't need horizontal. It just bugs me that I don't seem to be able to get horizontal working and am sure I will need it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove `width:'100%'` from the `row` view? A View defaults to `Ti.UI.FILL` so you shouldn't need to set the `width` to `100%` and maybe by doing so it is causing troubles?

Answer (score 0):

The above code works when i tried it on my system.
I only removed the require and widget statements from .xml file
and used 
right:0 OR left : "50%"